# How can I make a circle using css and apply it to my header?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have been searching the web for the past 2 hours trying to find how to achieve this result:

[image]

But I don't want to use images. I was trying to use the :after selector to achieve that result.

Is it possible.

I'm so sorry if this has been asked 200x , but I couldn't find it. I swear that I searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in using the :after pseudo-class. My assumption is that you possibly forgot to specify the `content: ''` attribute.

So first, you're going to want to create a block and position it at the bottom of your header:

```
header { position: relative; }
header:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: -22px; // Pull it out to half of its size for the semi-circle look
    width: 44px;
}
```

Then make it circular using border-radius:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 44px;
   -moz-border-radius: 44px;
        border-radius: 44px;
```

---

Final code:

```
header:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: -22px; // Pull it out to half of its size for the semi-circle look
    width: 44px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 44px;
       -moz-border-radius: 44px;
            border-radius: 44px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Huge help. Got it!

Comment: Vendor prefix can be removed now. This property is officially supported by browsers long ago.

Comment: @LeoDeng any source for that? I know the modern browsers now have complete support for border-radius alone, but from my (albeit short) research it seems that the older versions do in fact need the prefixes to work; It just depends whether you want to support them or not.

Comment: [**This link**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius). Click **show all** and see the complete chart. "supported with prefix" is history. Unless you want to support those old stuff. Also you may search for market share of different versions of browser. I don't think back compatible for this is necessary anymore.

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like you're right. I'm just used to Compass spitting out the vendor prefixes, I guess

Answer (score 1):

To make simple circle in HTML, make a square `div`, apply a `border-radius` of 50% and you'll have a circle.

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

And in your CSS :

```
.circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;       
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uw885d84/

Then, to place it, there are many ways, a simple one is to set your parent as `position: relative` and use absolute (`position: absolute`) positionning on your "circle" to place it at the center.

**Edit** Josh Burgess' answer shows a good way to position it.

Answer (score 0):

We're going to use `border-radius` property to achieve this with pseudo-elements.

Basically, if you round the div to *at least* 50% of its height and width, you get a circle.

Then, we position it absolutely at the bottom center of the `header` and voila.

```
header {
 position: relative;
}
header:after {
 content: '';
 border-radius: 40px;
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 100%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background-color: blue;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're having overlap issues, this will work as well:

```
header:after {
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
  background:blue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

and will generate a half circle (downwards facing) at the bottom of your header.